# Error: “The operation was rejected by your operating system” when trying to update expo-cli

Tags: react-native, expo

> npm ERR! code EPERM
> npm ERR! syscall rename
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\Avinash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli
> npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Avinash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.expo-cli-MaHHbGHy
> npm ERR! errno -4048
> npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Avinash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli' -> 'C:\Users\Avinash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.expo-cli-MaHHbGHy'
> npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Avinash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli' -> 'C:\Users\Avinash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.expo-cli-MaHHbGHy'] {
> npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
> npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
> npm ERR!   path: 'C:\Users\Avinash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli',
> npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\Users\Avinash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.expo-cli-MaHHbGHy'
> npm ERR! }
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
> npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Avinash\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-28T06_08_17_131Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

Please try following steps:

1. check your antivirus status is enable or disable
2. disable your antivirus during the installation.

I hope this helps. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd as administrator , this is permission error

Also try to see if the file is in use :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015880627-How-to-Identify-which-Windows-Process-is-Locking-a-File-or-Folder

> Open Process Explorer
> Running as administrator. On the toolbar, find the gunsight icon on the right. Drag the icon and drop it on the open file or folder
> that is locked. The executable that is using the file will be
> highlighted in the Process Explorer main display list.

Answer (score 0):

Alongside opening your command prompt window with administrator privileges, try killing the process `adb.exe`, which can be found by opening your Task Manager and navigating to the Details tab. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2848) has a few other possible solutions you can try.

Answer (score 0):

I found it was because I had the folder open in my code editor. Closed it and ran the npm install command and it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31138881)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have explorer or some folder open. Closing that folder/explorer solved my problem